# Is Toast allowed from an Android appWidget?

Tags: android, toast, android-appwidget

I would like to pop-up an error from the appwidget when one of its background tasks fails, but I don't think that is permissible -- or if it works, that it is safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, as long as you have a reference to a valid Context object, it is safe to create a Toast.

However, in your case, I think you might be better off using the Notification Bar's API.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html

It would probably give your users a better experience to not have your app interrupt their screen space to tell them your app didn't do what it was supposed to.  To the average user, that's two reasons to uninstall that they suddenly have.

Comment: Much better recommendation.  I already removed the Toast and using Log for the time being.  The notification bar makes much more sense.